# Loosing connection with Redis(aioredis) inside aiohttp app

Tags: python-3.x, redis, publish-subscribe, aiohttp

I am building a `text/event-stream` based view in `aiohttp` and also using pub-sub from Redis in `aioredis`implementaion. It looks something like:

#### Script that get some data from server and publish into chanell

```
def main(host, port):
    server_logger.info('Got params connection host {0}, port {1}'.format(host, port))
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    title = None
    redis = loop.run_until_complete(create_redis(('localhost', 6379)))
    while True:
        new_title = loop.run_until_complete(get_title(host, port))
        if new_title != title:
            loop.run_until_complete(redis.publish('CHANNEL', new_title))
            title = new_title
    loop.close()
    return False
```

#### aiohttp view that subscribe for channel and write it into Stream response

```
stream = web.StreamResponse()
stream.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
stream.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
stream.headers['Connection'] = 'keep-alive'

await stream.prepare(request)

redis = await create_redis(('localhost', 6379))
channel = (await redis.subscribe('CHANNEL'))[0]

while await channel.wait_message():
        message = await channel.get()
        if message:
            stream.write(b'event: track_update\r\n')
            stream.write(b'data: ' + message + b'\r\n\r\n')
        else:
            continue
```

And I got a lot of times something like :

```
DEBUG:aioredis:Creating tcp connection to ('localhost', 6379)
```

So sonnection is lost which also cause `concurrent.futures.CancelledError` and keep-alive connection will be lost.
Is that ok that connection is lost such often? I was expecting to have persistent connection, sorry if I am missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first creation new redis connection in request handler is bad idea.
Please use a connection pool per application.

You might get https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/blob/master/demos/polls/aiohttpdemo_polls/main.py as a sketch for recommended design principles.

Regarding to keep-alived connections -- they are not very persistent but closed after 75 secs inactivity period by default.

You may increase the period by passing `keep_alive=300` parameter into `app.make_handler()` call but setting very big value is not robust -- during TCP nature connection may be broken without notifications under some conditions.
Better to keep reasonable slow timeout and send custom ping requests to the server periodically if you have no data to pass.

Comment: thanks for answer. But in case `text/event-stream` connection is only one way, so I will not be able to send ping from client to server.

Comment: In this case just increase `keep_alive` timeout to insane value and keep fingers crossed

Comment: It looks like there are some additional server timing added to `keep_alive` time. With value `120` I end up with `170` seconds timeout for request. Anyway, your response clarified a lot for me. Was not able to find any "real" examples of usage SSE(dealing with timeouts etc.) in the net. I am not sure now if SSE fits for sending data with interval 3-6 mins from server :( And websocket here is overhead because I have only one way data flow.